# Return how many times a positive integer can be divided by two before reaching 1

Tags: python

Using basic python methods, create a function that takes a positive integer and answers the question: How many times can n be halved before reaching 1?

I m not sure how to even begin this one. I know I need a count function, but I am not sure how I would use that function. And would I use n//2 < 1 or n%2 == 1

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what if it is an odd number?

Comment: Looks like homework! Give it a try yourself and post your problems instead! you use / to divide and % to perform modulus.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import math
math.log(100, 2)
```

Comment: Where im confused is that it requires that we use a while loop