# calculate how many times a number can be halved before reaching 1

Tags: python

The questions is to write a function that tells how many times 'n' can be halves before reaching 1. I have been working on making this code work, but its not working. I thought i had it with this one, but when I try to test it with mystery(4) or with anything else, it returns 0 ever time. Can someone tell me what needs fixing. Here is what I have:

```
def mystery(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 0
      if n//2 > 1:
         count = count + 1
    print (count)
```

Comment: This doesn't ever return `0`, it returns `None` every time. Because you don't have a `return` statement.

Comment: What was wrong with the `math.log` solution in [the previous version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187031/return-how-many-times-a-positive-integer-can-be-divided-by-two-before-reaching-1)?

Comment: Actually, strike that, it can't even compile, because you're (at least) missing a colon. And, if you fix that, it will just run in an infinite loop, because you never modify `n` anywhere.

Comment: So, if you want to ask us why your code always returns 0, you have to show us the code that always returns 0, not some completely different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def mystery (n):
    count = 0
    while n > 1:
        n = n / 2
        count = count + 1
    if n == 1:
        return count
    return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't modifying the value of n. Try:

```
def mystery(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 1:
        n = n // 2
        count += 1
    return count
```

(untested)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being a wise guy ;)

```
from math import log, ceil
def mystery(n):
  return ceil(log(n, 2))
```

Comment: You could use math.log(n, 2)

Comment: @Yossi, right I was just about to do that.

Comment: It requires that I use a while loop and I am not sure how to do that and get it to work?

Comment: I like this one way better than my own answer

Comment: +1 I'm amazed people are even considering other solution. It's a trick question!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have fixed the comments made already the reason your code will run for ever is that you have a `while n>0`. Since each iteration you update by `n/2` this will never be negative!